# How can i using SignalR in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

How can i using SignalR in Android studio. I connect to server which made by .Net. But when I send request. It is disconnected. I asked 3 times but nobody rep. Help me .
in .Net

```
public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(String user)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(user);
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user);
        }
    }
```

In Android Studio.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());

        textView =findViewById(R.id.textView);
        hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder.create("http://10.0.2.2:5000/chatHub").build();

        hubConnection.on("ReceiveMessage",(user)->{
            textView.setText(user);
        },String.class);

        hubConnection.start();

    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        user = "Nam";
        if(hubConnection.getConnectionState()== HubConnectionState.CONNECTED){
            hubConnection.send("SendMessage",user);
            textView.setText("Sent");

        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: Do not write the same question a few times if you do not get an answer. Instead, edit it! Imagine why no one can or will answer your question and [edit] it so you get more answers. **It is forbidden to repost the same answer!**

Comment: 1 day have over 100 question. I scare it can be nobody can see

Comment: nope - you have a total of 3 questions and btw. please use google translator if your English isn't the best.